# Solving $\cos\phi\cos(2\theta - \phi)+\sin(\theta - \phi)\sin(\theta + \phi)=0$ for $\theta$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Let $$ d = \frac{2v_i \cos(\theta)\sin(\theta - \phi)}{g\cos^2\phi} $$
Now I have to equate $\frac{d}{d\theta}$ to $0$ and find $\theta$.
$$\frac{(2(v_i)^2\sin{\theta}\sin(\theta - \phi)+2(v_i)^2\cos{\theta}\cos(\theta - \phi))g\cos^2\theta+4(v_i)^2\cos{\theta}\sin(\theta - \phi)g\cos{\theta}\sin\phi}{g^2\cos^4\phi}=0$$
Then I get to the following expression: $$-\cos{\phi}\sin{\theta}\sin({\theta - \phi})+\cos{\theta}\cos(\theta - \phi)\cos\phi+2\cos{\theta}\sin(\theta - \phi)\sin \theta=0$$

$$\cos\phi\cos(2\theta - \phi)+\sin(\theta - \phi)\sin(\theta + \phi)=0$$
I need to get to $\theta = \frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{\phi}{2}$ but I don't know how to continue. I tried different ways but I never get to the desired solution.

Comment: Have you tried the angle-addition formulas?

Comment: This $$-\cos{\phi}\sin{\theta}\sin({\theta - \phi})+\cos{\theta}\cos(\theta - \phi)\cos\phi+2\cos{\theta}\sin(\theta - \phi)\sin \theta=0$$ will be equal to $cos(\phi)cos(2\theta-\phi)+sin(\theta-\phi)sin(2\theta)$

Comment: This looks like a physics question. Is $d$ the distance, $v_i$ the initial velocity, and $g$ the gravity scalar? If so, you can pull them out of the derivative to make things a little easier.

Comment: It looks like you miscalculated the derivative and basically need to start over. Try doing it step by step, and write down exactly what you are doing and why at each step.

Comment: @DavidK yes he made mistakes in the derivative I think... Some of them are visible directly

Comment: If you familiarize yourself with the product-to-sum formulas, in this particular case they simplify things a lot.

Comment: Assuming you have copied the formula for $d$ correctly, its derivative with respect to $\theta$ is zero at $\frac\pi4 + \frac\phi2$, not $\frac\pi4 - \frac\phi2$. I advise checking the problem very carefully to make sure you are trying to solve the right thing.

Answer (score 3):

use Mathematica `Solve`

```
Solve[Cos[\[Phi]]*Cos[2 \[Theta] - \[Phi]] + 
    Sin[\[Theta] - \[Phi]]*Sin[\[Theta] + \[Phi]] == 0, \[Theta], 
  Assumptions -> {\[Theta] \[Element] Reals, \[Phi] \[Element] 
     Reals}] // FullSimplify
```

$$
\left\{\left\{\theta \to \fbox{$\frac{1}{2} \pi  (4 c_1-1)\text{ if }c_1\in \mathbb{Z}$}\right\},\left\{\theta \to \fbox{$\frac{1}{2} (4 \pi  c_1+\pi )\text{ if }c_1\in \mathbb{Z}$}\right\},\left\{\theta \to \fbox{$2 \phi +\pi  \left(2 c_1-\frac{1}{2}\right)\text{ if }c_1\in \mathbb{Z}$}\right\},\left\{\theta \to \fbox{$\frac{1}{2} (4 \phi +4 \pi  c_1+\pi )\text{ if }c_1\in \mathbb{Z}$}\right\}\right\}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Since you want the critical points, then want the local maximum or local minimum of $d$ as a function of $\theta$.  This can be tackled directly from the expression for $d$.  $\phi$ is fixed, so what we should concentrate on is

$ f(\theta) = \cos(\theta) \sin(\theta - \phi) $

Using the identity

$ cos(A) sin(B) = 1/2 ( \sin(B + A) + \sin(B - A) ) $

We get

$ f(\theta) = 1/2 ( \sin( 2 \theta - \phi) + \sin(- \phi) ) $

The second term is constant, and does not depend on $\theta$.  So the maximum of $f$ is when

$2 \theta - \phi = \dfrac{\pi}{2} $

This leads to $ \theta = \dfrac{\phi}{2} + \dfrac{\pi}{4} $

If you looking for the minimum then this occurs when

$ 2 \theta - \phi = - \dfrac{\pi}{2} $

And this leads to $ \theta = \dfrac{\phi}{2} - \dfrac{ \pi}{4} $

Answer (score 2):

I got the expression $\cos \theta \cos ( \theta-
\varphi) = \sin \theta \sin ( \theta-\varphi) $ from the derivative to solve for $\theta$. This gets expanded out to

$$ \cos \theta ( \cos \varphi \cos \theta + \sin \varphi \sin \theta) = \sin \theta ( \cos \varphi \sin \theta - \sin \varphi \cos \theta) \tag{1} $$

Now apply the [tangent-half-angle substitution(s)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution) of

$$ \begin{array}{c|c}
z = \tan \left( \tfrac{\varphi}{2} \right) & t = \tan \left( \tfrac{\theta}{2} \right) \\ 
\varphi = 2 \tan^{-1}(z) & \theta = 2 \tan^{-1}(t) \\ \hline
\cos(\varphi) = \tfrac{1-z^2}{1+z^2} & \cos(\theta) = \tfrac{1-t^2}{1+t^2} \\
\sin(\varphi) = \tfrac{2 z}{1+z^2} & \sin(\theta) = \tfrac{2 t}{1+t^2}
\end{array} \tag{2}$$

The result is

$$\small \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2} \left( \frac{(1-z^2)(1-t^2)}{(1+z^2)(1+t^2)} + \frac{(2 z)(2 t)}{(1+z^2)(1+t^2)} \right) = \frac{2 t}{1+t^2} \left( \frac{(2 t)(1-z^2)}{(1+z^2)(1+t^2)} - \frac{(1-t^2)(2 z)}{(1+z^2)(1+t^2)} \right) $$

which is simplified by eliminating common terms down to

$$ (1-t^2)(z^2 (1-t^2)-4 t z + t^2-1) = 4 t (t z^2 + (1-t)^2 z -t) $$

Finally, bring both sides together to get

$$ (1-z^2) t^4 -8 z t^3 - 6 (1-z^2) t^2 + (8 z) t + (1-z^2) = 0 \tag{3} $$

which is a solvable quatric polynomial in terms of $t$ and hence $\theta = 2 \tan^{-1}(t)$

If you restict $\varphi = 0 \ldots \pi/2$ then $z (1-z^2) \ge 0$ and the four solutions of $t$ are

$$ \large t = \begin{cases}
\text{-} \frac{ \sqrt{2} (1-z) \sqrt{1+z^2}-z^2-2z-1}{1-z^2} \\
\text{+} \frac{ \sqrt{2} (1-z) \sqrt{1+z^2}+z^2+2z+1}{1-z^2} \\
\text{-} \frac{ \sqrt{2} (1+z) \sqrt{1+z^2}+z^2-2z+1}{1-z^2} \\
\text{+} \frac{ \sqrt{2} (1+z) \sqrt{1+z^2}-z^2+2z-1}{1-z^2} \\
\end{cases} \tag{4} $$

Expanded out, the above is also written as

$$ \large \tan \left( \frac{\theta}{2} \right) = \begin{cases}
 \frac{(1+\sin(\varphi))\sqrt{1+\cos(\varphi)}-\cos(\varphi)+\sin(\varphi)-1}{\cos(\varphi)\sqrt{1+\cos(\varphi)}} \\
 \frac{(1+\sin(\varphi))\sqrt{1+\cos(\varphi)}+\cos(\varphi)-\sin(\varphi)+1}{\cos(\varphi)\sqrt{1+\cos(\varphi)}} \\
 \frac{(\sin(\varphi)-1)\sqrt{1+\cos(\varphi)}-\cos(\varphi)-\sin(\varphi)-1}{\cos(\varphi)\sqrt{1+\cos(\varphi)}} \\
\frac{(\sin(\varphi)-1)\sqrt{1+\cos(\varphi)}+\cos(\varphi)+\sin(\varphi)+1}{\cos(\varphi)\sqrt{1+\cos(\varphi)}} \\
\end{cases}$$

Comment: PS I used `Derive` to solve the quartic polynomial.